Xamarin App CrossMedia Camera Crashes on Android
We are using the CrossMedia plugin to take photos in our Xamarin Android app.  Most of the time it works without any problem.  Sometimes, users in the field experience a crash while using the camera.  When this happens, the app just "falls in the pond" (so to speak) - our exception handler never gets control and the app just quits (abends):
 private async void CapturePhoto()
 {
     try
     {
         PhotoButton.IsVisible = false;

         string aName = CreateImageName();

         StoreCameraMediaOptions options = new StoreCameraMediaOptions()
         {
             Name = aName,
             Directory = "OURAPP",
             SaveToAlbum = false,
             CompressionQuality = 100,
             CustomPhotoSize = 50,
             PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
             MaxWidthHeight = 1024,
             DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front
             
         };

         var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(options);

         await DisplayAlert("INFO","Got your photo. Will copy to your app folder...", "OK" );

         string filePath = CopyFileToExternalPhotosFolderAndDeleteOriginal(file.Path);

         _viewModel.Add(new PhotoViewModel
         {
             Path = filePath,
             Source = filePath
         });

         PhotoButton.IsVisible = true;
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         await DisplayAlert("Ooops!", $"Something went wrong retrieving the photo:\n{e.Message}", "Dismiss");
     }
     finally
     {
         PhotoButton.IsVisible = true;
     }
 }

So my questions are 1) What could cause the camera to crash randomly?  2) Why does our exception handler never get control when this error occurs? 3) How best to debug this? and 4) What are the best alternatives to the CrossMedia plugin for taking photos?
